# Typescript dictionary with dynamic keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to typescript and struggling to describe a dictionary.

Basically I export several stores (the example below is reduced on purpose), which I feed to a Registry class.

Ideally the **stores dictionary** type I would like to be dynamic in a way that I can export as  many stores I want, but when I try to use the registry in my component and try to access something that is not in the **stores dict**, TS will complain and the IDE will pick it up.

Any TS wizardry will be much appreciated

stores.ts

```
import UserStore from './user.ts';
import ListStore from './list.ts';
export {
   UserStore, ListStore
};
```

registry.ts

```
export default class Registry{

    stores = {};

    constructor(stores: any){
        Object.keys(stores).forEach((name: string) => {
            const cls = stores[name];
            this.stores[name] = new cls(this);
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE based on the answer provided below. I changed the registry to this. All stores derive from BaseStore.
However, I don't get TS complaining when I try to access a non existent store**

```
export default class Registry{

    stores: { [name: string]: BaseStore } = {};


    constructor(stores: any){
        Object.keys(stores).forEach((name: string) => {
            const cls = stores[name];
            if(cls){
                this.stores[name] = new cls(this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What makes a store a store?  `Store` subclasses?  A link to a minimal, reproducible example on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) would be helpful.

Comment: @fedonev A "store" is a concept in Redux, Flux, and ReactJS. It's not possible to make a TS Playground example because you need the rest of ReactJS available.

Comment: How would you call/instantiate the Registry class? Could you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 2):

```js
type storeType = {
    [key: string]: any // instead of any you can put any type you want...
}
```

now `stores` can have this:

```
const stores = {
    'userStore': 'anything',
    'listStore': 'anything'
}

console.log(stores.userStore) // will accept the type
```

Comment: I'd upvote you, but this is not a suitable use of `any` in TypeScript today.

Comment: I think this is more a way to bypass the TS checker and not really the way we should want to implement such things

Comment: @Yitzhak I tried that already. However, this way I do not get the IDE complaining if I try to reference a non existent store

Comment: yea well that's because you are asking that stores will be dynamic, 
you can have it be dynamic and complain if the store does not exist at the same time,
you need to decide if you want to add each time new store to the ```type store``` (for example) or just do a dynamic type as I wrote above